# Javascript - copy from sweetalert2 button confirm

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

how can I copy from my button "Copy URLs" when is clicked?

```
function cdwUrlsMDBE() {
            var prd = document.getElementById("prd");

            if (prd.checked == true) {
                Swal.fire({
                    type: 'success',
                    html: 'i am a text that should be copy',
                    width: 'auto',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Copy URLs',
                })
```

Thanks

Comment: you want the copy button to only copy after the 'Copy URLs' is clicked?  Look at the `onClose` here https://sweetalert2.github.io/#configuration then include something like the function in the example on this blog https://hackernoon.com/copying-text-to-clipboard-with-javascript-df4d4988697f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it creating a button via **html** and **Bootstrap**, in this way you could attach an handler on the button via **onOpen**.

Something like this

```
Swal.fire({
    title: "Copy it!",
    html: 
        '<textarea id="text_to_be_copied" class="swal2-input" readonly>Some text you want to copy</textarea>' +
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-copy" style="margin-left:5px">Copy</button>' +
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary swal-confirm" id="btn-ok" style="float:right" disabled>Text have been copied!</button>' +
        '</div>',
    showConfirmButton: false,
    type: "success",
    onOpen: () => {
        $("#btn-copy").click(() => {
            $("#btn-ok").prop('disabled', false);

            $("#text_to_be_copied").select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
        });

        $("#btn-ok").click(() => {
            Swal.close();   
        });
    }
});
```

In this way the "confirmation button" is displayed only after you use the copy one, but you could decide to get rid of that just by putting `Swal.close()` inside the handler of the copy button. In this way after clicking che copy button, the popUp will close.

You could choose to use also an input tag instead of a textarea depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var txtToBeCopied ='i am a text that should be copy';

    if (prd.checked == true) {
                Swal.fire({
                    type: 'success',
                    html: txtToBeCopied,
                    width: 'auto',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Copy URLs',
                },
 function(isConfirm){

   if (isConfirm){

     /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = txtToBeCopied;

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");


    }
 })
 }
```